# Maximize the volume given triangle's perimeter

Tags: calculus, geometry, triangles, volume, lagrange-multiplier

Anys ideas?

Find the triangle with perimeter 2p given that, when we rotate it around one of its sides, the solid obtained have the maximum volume.

Comment: Is this problem related to Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @edionz:  that's a sensible place to start since you're supposed to maximize a scalar over a convex region using calculus.  Haven't tried it for this problem though (or particularly remember the problem from college)